# In converting input to list of floats, split() is not working

Tags: python, split

I am trying to create a program that will help some people working my lab. I'm also a very novice programmer.

My code is breaking down at what I thought was a simple few lines in which I convert an input list of numbers (e.g. 675.23, 781.30, 979.10 ...), by default a string, into floats.

For example:

```
inputNumbers = input("Please type your numbers here (comma separated): ")
inputNumbers.split(", ")
```

Then I run a for loop to convert into floats in a new list:

```
inputNumbersConv = []
for i in inputNumbers:
    inputNumbersConv.append(float(i))
```

This bugs out, though, and tells me that I can't convert "." into a float. The .split() above is not separating by commas. If you input 1.23 and run

```
print(inputNumbers[1])
```

you get "."

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried different delimiters, including just spaces.

Comment: `split` does not operate in-place.  You need to assign the result somewhere, e.g. `inputNumbers = inputNumbers.split(", ")`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting `inputNumbers` to the result of `inputNumbers.split(", ")`. As a result `inputNumbers` remains your raw user input when you iterate through it in the for loop.

A more concise implementation of your program would be:

```
inputNumbers = map(float, input("Please type your numbers here (comma separated): ").split(", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, you need to assign the array of split values to a variable on the LHS to use later:

```py
inputNumbers = input("Please type your numbers here (comma separated): ")
nums = inputNumbers.split(", ")

inputNumbersConv = []
for i in nums:
    inputNumbersConv.append(float(i))
print(inputNumbersConv)
```

For an input of `675.23, 781.30, 979.10`, the printed output was:

```
[675.23, 781.3, 979.1]
```

Comment: I held the incorrect assumption that all methods operate in place. Thanks, all I needed to do was assign a new variable.